# Best way to Refresh Environment (GKE) using helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, kubernetes-helm

I am creating environment on GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine ) using Terraform. I am creating and destroying environment.
For application packaging and destroying I am using Helm charts. After every build deployment is done using Helm via Terraform Apply Command. It takes time to refresh the environment using Terraform + Helm deployment around 10-30 mins.

I want to bring down the environment refresh time with new artifacts, Keeping helm into the process.
What is the best practice I should follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `helm upgrade` instead of Helm delete and create.